# Proof periodic equation

Tags: sequences-and-series, functional-equations, periodic-functions

I don't understand how he get $b- \sqrt2, -a, -b$....

and what is the periodic function?

[image: image here]

Answer (score 0):

A periodic function is a function such that there exist $p > 0$, such that for all $x\in \mathbf{R}, f(x+p) = f(x)$. Here, he is using $f(x+1) = \sqrt 2 f(x) - f(x-1)$ to compute $f(x+n)$ for $n$ integer and see what is happening. He shows that $f(x+4) = -f(x)$ and deduces $f(x+8) = - f(x+4) = f(x)$

Comment: I'm sorry but I'm still confused..
Do you mean that f(x) = f(x+1) = f(x+2) = f(x+3) = ...?
If you mean that then how he gets f(x+2) = b-√2 a
Thanks in advance.